# How to setup ZERO-MQ architecture to deal with workers of different speed

Tags: c++, networking, zeromq

[as a small context provider: I am new to networking and ZERO-MQ, but I did spend quite a bit of time on the guide and examples]

I have the following challenge (done in C++, but irrelevant to the question). I have a single source that generates tasks. I have multiple engines that need to process those tasks, and send back the result.

**First attempt:**
I created a client with a ZMQ_PUSH socket. The engines have a ZMQ_PULL socket. To get the answers back to the client, I created the reverse: a ZMQ_PUSH on the workers and a ZMQ_PULL on the client. It worked out of the box. Only to find out that after some time the client ran out of memory since I was pushing way more requests than the workers could process. I need some backpressure.

**Second attempt:**
I added a counter on the client that took care of only pushing when no more than say 1000 tasks were 'in progress'. The out of memory issue was solved, since I was never having more than 1000 'in progress' tasks. But ... some workers were slower than others. Since PUSH/PULL uses fair queueing, the amount of work for that slow worker kept increasing and increasing...until the slowest worker had all 1000 requests queued and the others were starved. I was not using my workers effectively.

Now, what architecture could I use that solves the issue of 'workers with different speed'? Is the 'count the number of in progress tasks' approach a good way of balancing the number of pushed requests? Or is there a way I can PUSH tasks to the workers, and the pushing blocks on a predefined point? Can I do that with HWM?

I am sure this problem is of such a generic nature that I should be able to easily deal with this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

we used the Paranoid Pirate Protocol http://rfc.zeromq.org/spec:6,

but in case of many very small jobs, where the overhead of communication might be high, a credit-based flow control pattern might be more efficient. http://unprotocols.org/blog:15

in both cases it is necessary for the requester to directly assign jobs to individual workers.  this is abstracted away of course and, depending on the use-case, could be made available as a sync call, which returns when all tasks have been processed.